# Как сделать так чтобы сайдбар был открытым при клике?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на каждый брэнд он оставался открытым с выпадающим списком категорий внутри. К примеру кликнул, и остается открытым, чтобы дать пользователю понять что есть категорию как в скрине.
Ссылка на проект http://vca.kz/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$('.click-pr').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr').slideToggle();
});
$('.click-pr2').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr2').slideToggle();
});
$('.click-pr3').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr3').slideToggle();
});
$('.click-pr4').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr4').slideToggle();
});
$('.click-pr5').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr5').slideToggle();
});
$('.click-pr6').click(function(){
    $('.show-pr6').slideToggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="goods-widget col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h3>Продукция</h3>
    <div class="click-pr">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi">OTTOGI</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr">
        <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi/ramen">Рамен</a> <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi/suxari">Сухари</a> <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi/klyar">Кляр</a> <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi/kunzhutnoe-maslo">Кунжутное масло</a>
    </div>
    <div class="click-pr2">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/sajo-hapyo">Sajo Hapyo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr2"></div>
    <div class="click-pr3">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/natura-bogata">Natura Bogata</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr3"></div>
    <div class="click-pr4">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/too-malu">ТОО Малу</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr4"></div>
    <div class="click-pr5">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/dongsuh">Dongsuh</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr5">
        <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/dongsuh/suxie-slivki">Сухие сливки</a> <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/dongsuh/suxoe-moloko">Сухое молоко</a>
    </div>
    <div class="click-pr6">
        <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ooo-maj">ООО Май</a>
    </div>
    <div class="show-pr6">
        <a class="category-pr" href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ooo-maj/chaj">Чай</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все просто, записываешь в куки что сайдбар открыт/закрыт и готово

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вам нужно это:

```js
'use strict';

$('.dropdown-toggle a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.target).parent('.dropdown-toggle').next('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="goods-widget col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <h3>Продукция</h3>
  <div class="dropdown-toggle"> <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/ottogi">OTTOGI</a> </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu hide"> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Рамен</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Сухари</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кляр</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кунжутное масло</a> </div>
  <div class="dropdown-toggle"> <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/sajo-hapyo">Sajo Hapyo</a> </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu hide"> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Рамен</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Сухари</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кляр</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кунжутное масло</a> </div>
  <div class="dropdown-toggle"> <a href="produkcziya/kartochka-tovara/natura-bogata">Natura Bogata</a> </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu hide"> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Рамен</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Сухари</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кляр</a> <a class="category-pr" href="#">Кунжутное масло</a> </div>
</div>
```

- Переключателю(при клике на который будет открываться список ниже) задавайте класс `dropdown-toggle`.
- Списку(который будет появляться/исчезать) задавайте класс `dropdown-menu` и `hide`.

---

У вас неоптимально написан HTML в данном блоке, я брал код из вашего примера, но лучше(если это возможно) переписать HTML. Я могу написать пример корректного HTML + JS.